# Why is this acoustic scattering integral a Fourier transform?

Tags: acoustics, fourier-transform

I am puzzeled about this part in the book "Acoustic Absorbers and Diffusors" from  T. J. Cox, P. and D'Antonio. It describes the scattered pressure from a surface of a pressure source in front of the surface.

[image: From the book T. J. Cox, P. D'Antonio - Acoustic Absorbers]

[image]

It is written that the integral term in this equation is "essentially a Fourier transform" but I don't see the connection of the term "sin($\theta$)," where theta is the angle of reflection, with the Fourier Transform. Why is this a Fourier transform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the authors mean by "neglect the $[\cos{\theta} + 1]$", but I'm guessing it's that the angle $\theta$ is such that
$$[\cos{\theta} + 1] \approx 1.$$ This would imply $\theta = \pi/2.$ In turn, $\sin{\theta} = 1$, reducing the integral to the familiar form of the Fourier transform:

$$p_s(\mathbf{r}) = \mathrm{something} \cdot \int_{-a}^a R(\mathbf{r_s}) \,\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{j} k x_s}\, \mathrm{d}x_s.$$

The only thing that doesn't check out is why the limits on the integral are $\pm a$ instead of $\pm \infty$ like in a proper FT.

Edit: Per OP's clarification, if the integrand is zero everywhere *except* in $-a \leq x_s \leq +a$ (i.e. a "window" of sorts), then the integral is indeed a Fourier Transform with the limits effectively $\pm a$.

Comment: this must be it. Thank you. Well i think the panel has only a finite size (form -a to a), hence it acts like a window function. unfortunately the author is not clear at all.

Comment: Edited my answer accounting for your comment.

Comment: $cos(\theta )\approx 1$ for small $\theta$ so that $[\cos{\theta} + 1] \approx 2$. The author ignored this term because it is a constant and can be absorbed into the other coefficients of the integral without changing the physics.